# Android Linkedin-J not posting network updates

Tags: android, linkedin-j

I'm trying to post a network update using Linkedin-J.
Here is my code:

```
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(linkedin_app_id, linkedin_app_secret);
final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(token, tokenSecret);
client.postNetworkUpdate(message);
```

No exception occures but nothing is posted.

The app status is Live and I tried in vain removing my own account from the developpers list.

Comment: I'm aware there is not a lot of code but that's the full code! These lines are executed after a click on a button. Variables are self describing: app key, app secret, user token and user token secret. Tokens were saved after the user was authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(linkedin_app_id, linkedin_app_secret);

client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(new LinkedInAccessToken(tokens, tokenSecret);

client.postNetworkUpdate(message);